# Adding to a specific position in a vector

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector

here is a code I have so far:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base();
    void addClass(int index);
    vector<Class*> classList;
};

void Base::addClass(int index)
{
    if(classList.at(index) ) //want to check if there is nothing already store at
                             //that index
    {
        Class* c = new Class();
        //want to add this ^ to the classList vector at the index
    }
    //and so on

}
```

How would I go about doing this? It seems simple, but I'm still stuck. Any and all help with be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: what if there is already an item in that index?

Comment: First of all you should make sure that the `index` is actually *valid*, i.e. that it's at least zero and that it's smaller than `classList.length()`. Otherwise just use `push_back`.

Comment: Where will this be used? Why are you trying to add the class at a certain point in the vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vector is sequential; there is something at every position
between 0 and `classList.size()`, and nothing elsewhere.  In the case of
pointers (and some other things), the contents *can* be a null
pointer, so while there is something, it is a very special
something, which can be considered nothing at a higher level.
If that's what you're looking for:

```
void
Base::addClass( int index )
{
    if ( classList.size() <= index ) {
        classList.resize( index + 1 );
    }
    if ( classList[index] == nullptr ) {
        classList[index] = new Class();
    }
}
```

First make sure that the vector is big enough, then test for the
`nullptr`.

The vector will still contain entries for every index up to
`classList.size()`.  If you call `addClass` once, with an
`index` of 1000000, that's going to mean a lot of empty entries.
If this is your use case, then you should probably consider some
sort of sparce data structure (perhaps a `std::map<int,
Class*`).  If the `index` aren't sparsely distributed, the
vector solution is good.

And one last point: it's almost never appropriate to use
`std::vector<>::at()`.  If an out of bounds index is
a programming error, you want the program to crash (which is the
usual behavior in non-optimizing builds); what you don't want in
case of a program error is to unwind the stack (in the usual
case—there are exceptions).

Comment: According to the data I wish to sort, there should be no empty or null pointers in between. But thank you for your advice, it was very thoughtful. And about the at() method... would it be okay to use it if I want to modify data that is already there? If not, what would you recommend?

Comment: Why are you recommending using `[]` over `at`? The latter checks for out of bounds for you. (I have a feeling this is what you are trying to explain in your last paragraph but I didn't follow it very well - perhaps you could rephrase?)

Comment: @starsplusplus In any decent implementation, `[]` will also check bounds, at least in non-optimizing builds.  And will cause the program to crash immediately, which is what you want in the case of a programming error.  `at()` throws an exception, which is only a good solution if clients of your code expect it, and catch it.  It means that an out of bounds access is not an error, but an expected occurrence (although probably rare).  When you detect a programming error, it means that all bets are off; you can't be sure of anything, and so want to terminate as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `std::map<int, Class*>`.

If you insist on using `std::vector<Class*>`, you have to call the `resize()` function to allocate some space in advance.

Comment: He must have enough space due to `if(classList.at(index))`.

Comment: @herohuyongtao after `resize(n)`, vector will spare enough space just as @Rakibul Hasan did.

Comment: Hmm... I see... I would prefer to use vector though because the index itself is a data I want to use and I thought it would be simpler later when I look for the data I want. Thank you for answering though!!

Answer (score 0):

This would increase the classList size by one:

```
    Class* c = new Class();
    classList.insert(classList.begin() + index, c);
```

Comment: I see... but I do not want to increase my vector size when adding. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

You can subscript into a vector:

```
classList[index] = c;
```

You could also use the [`insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/) function, although there's no easy way to pass a numeric index. You must add to an iterator:

```
classList.insert(classList.begin() + index, c);
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I'll be using the classList[index] = c; method.

Comment: I dislike the [index] method.. you really should use iterators with vectors.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the `size` of the vector. Otherwise if `index` is greater than size, program will crash because of accessing invalid memory location.

```
void Base::addClass(int index)
{
   Class* c = new Class();
  if(classList.size()< index) //check size
  {
      classList.resize(index+1); //resize if less then index
      classList[index]=c; // this location must be empty, as it was just allocated by previous line
  }
  else if(classList.at(index) == NULL) //else if that location is empty, place it                             
  {
     classList[index]=c;
  }
  else{ //else add at the end of the vector
     classList.push_back(c)
  }
```

}

Comment: Why should we have a `else` branch? We should just ignore it when classList.at(index) == NULL.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is what I wanted to do exactly! Well except the else statement, but I didn't really get that far anyway ^^;

Comment: @qingfeng, I asked "what if there is already an item in that index?" in the comment, OP did not reply. So I generalized the solution. Was it a SIN? May God forgive my soul.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would suffice? this would replace the item at the index specified without using classList[i] (should use iterators with vectors).

```
Class* c = new Class();
classList.erase(classList.begin()+index);
classList.insert(classList.begin()+index, c);
```

working example: [here](http://ideone.com/9aEK37)